# One glyph of a font does not scale accordingly

Tags: fonts, glyph, font-scaling

I'm using a font (not mine) for writing things on an image by code.
Though every glyph scales well with each other, **one does not** (in that particular case, the number 2).

[image]

See as the number 2 scales differently comparing to the other glyphs (top left-hand corner).

I don't know much about how fonts work but I tried opening it in a font editing software.
However, I couldn't notice any striking difference between the number 2 and other glyphs (at first glance).

[image]

Any help would be very appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is most likely happening is that the glyph for 2 in that font has hinting data that is poorly implemented. Hints make adjustments to outlines and how they get rasterized for particular sizes. When hints are poorly implemented, you can see really strange artefacts that change at different sizes.

This is a risk of using free fonts: you get what you pay for.

Comment: Interesting. Is there anything we can do to fix this data? Are you referring to the vector-based representation I screenshot above?

Comment: The vector-based representation (actually, Bezier curves), are not the issue. The hinting data supplements that. You might be able to use a font editor to strip the hinting data from the 2 glyph. But if possible it would be better to contact the original font developer to have them fix their font.

Comment: I ended up deleting all hint data with a font editing software and it works well, thank you!